# Iterate through Array (strange dimension)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to iterate through this array, but I am unable to manage the dimension setting. Haven't seen an array like that before.
It will be creating while using the Split-function of VBA. How am I able to iterate through to second dimension?

Code snippet:

```
Dim arrTemp() As Variant: arrTemp = tblUserInput.DataBodyRange
    Dim arr() As Variant
    
    Dim arrtemp_Sheet() As Variant
    Dim arrtemp_Control() As Variant
    iCounter = 0
    For i = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
        If Not arrTemp(i, 5) = "" Then
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrtemp_Sheet(1 To iCounter)
            ReDim Preserve arrtemp_Control(1 To iCounter)
            arrtemp_Sheet(iCounter) = Split(arrTemp(i, 5), ";")
            arrtemp_Control(iCounter) = Split(arrTemp(i, 6), ";")
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim arrFinal_Sheet() As Variant
    For i = LBound(arrtemp_Sheet) To UBound(arrtemp_Sheet)
        For j = LBound(arrFinal_Sheet(i)) To UBound(arrFinal_Sheet(i)) <-- Error!
            Debug.Print arrFinal_Sheet(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
```

Background information:
I need all entries in that list being populated into an array one by one. and if a cell contains a ";", then I need to split it and put it also one after another into the array.
This is why I first create a temporary Array which collects the sheets and another temporary array which collects the controls names. I then want to merge them into a final array. Maybe there is even a better approach?

[image]

Comment: Your `arrFinal_Sheet()` does not have any dimension and it is not loaded. How to iterate between such an empty array? What are you trying to accomplish, in fact?

Comment: damnit. thanks. I bounded the incorrect object. no i managed to do so. (i)(j) will do the trick then.

Comment: Yes, this is a so named jagged array (array of arrays) and its iteration should be done as you tried...